# Green card holder applying for the UK visitor visa

Tags: proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-accommodation, proof-of-employment

I am a full time student in college and I also have a full time job that I have worked for 2 years. I want to visit Jersey The Channel island because my boyfriend lives there. Due to Covid- 19, my school is fully online. Therefore, I can be anywhere in the world as long as there is an internet connection. I have also been planning to quit my job when school starts because it is too difficult to balance full time school and work. But decides to stick for a while until I leave to travel.

I want to apply for the UK visa visitor, and stay in Jersey in my boyfriend’s house for a month. He also lives with his mother. I understand I will be required to quarantine for the first two weeks. I will be able to financially support myself. What are the documents that my boyfriend will need to provide? Will his mom too?. Does he need to show his bank statements and pay slips?

I am planning to quit my job when I travel, so I wont be able to provide them leave of absence letter. Is being a college student enough to convince them that I will not overstay? Should I ask my professors for “leave of absence”?

I applied for US citizenship back in February. Due to Covid, it has been delayed and the website says that I will have to attend the interview and oath ceremony in November. Will that be a good reason to return to the USA and not overstay in the UK?

I have $3000 in savings, is that enough fund for one month?

Comment: I think the possibility of getting your citizenship would be a good reason to come back to the U.S. but you need to provide proof that is the case. I'm not sure how that works. As to having $3,000, it's not advisable to use up all your savings for the trip because it signals you don't plan to come back. I would say it depends. In my recent visa application, I put GBP3,000 as my budget for 6 months but I was able to justify that by providing a list of expected expenses and citing references for why I put the figures.

Comment: You’re asking several questions at once, all of which are pretty much covered in the official Visit guidance https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf $3,000 is more than ample for a month long visit, especially when your accommodation etc is free and you’ll be in quarantine for half of the time.